# Custom ESLint/TypeScript indentation rules for parameters of method declaration

Tags: typescript, eslint

I'd like to be able to indent parameters in a method declaration so that they line up, but not be forced all the way into having to put each parameter on a separate line.

[image]

ESLint doesn't seem to have a rule for that, and I think I'll just have to give up having any indentation rules enforced at all within the list of my method's parameters. I can live with that.

I'm having a hard time figuring out the correct AST node syntax to express this, however. I'm using [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/), but I can't figure out the correct node syntax to describe what I'm seeing there.

[image]

I can use `MethodDefinition` by itself, but that only controls the indentation of the start of the method itself, not anything about the parameters.

I can us `MethodDefinition > :expression *`, but then no indentation rules are enforced within the entire body of the method. I don't want to disable that much linting.

I've tried syntax like `MethodDefinition > params > Identifier`, but that doesn't do anything. Other variations on that theme crash ESLint.

Can anyone clue me in about the correct ESLint syntax for what I'm trying to do? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I looks like I gave up too soon before posting here. The correct syntax is `MethodDefinition Identifier`. I guess the trick is to ignore any of the lowercase steps in the node hierarchy, and only specify the uppercase node types.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be the solution for the behavior you are looking for in the `.eslintrc.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  rules: {
    'indent': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/indent': ['warn', 2, {
      FunctionDeclaration: {
        parameters: 'first',
      },
    }],
  }
}
```